# how to clear/erase the content of found partition using sgdisk

Tags: partitioning, boot-partition

I have a requirement, if I found my partition using skids -p /dev/sdc then I need to clear the particular partition content. 
How can I do that using sgdisk command?

Suppose I found the Client_Image  partition and need to clear the content of that

```
# sudo sgdisk -p /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 15654912 sectors, 7.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 8C5B1844-CEAE-2370-00BD-D0E47E3C9900
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 15654878
Partitions will be aligned on 2-sector boundaries
Total free space is 0 sectors (0 bytes)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              34         2097151   1024.0 MiB  0700  Linux data
   2         2097152         8388607   3.0 GiB     0700  Shared FAT
   3         8388608        15654878   3.5 GiB     A503  Client_Image
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`sgdisk` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/sgdisk.8.html):

> ```
>    -d, --delete=partnum
>           Delete a partition. This action deletes the entry from the partition table but does
>           not disturb the data within the sectors originally allocated to  the  partition  on
>           the  disk.  If  a  corresponding  hybrid MBR partition exists, gdisk deletes it, as
>           well, and expands any adjacent 0xEE (EFI GPT) MBR protective partition to fill  the
>           new free space.
> ```

Therefore, to delete partition Client_Image (number 3)

```
sudo sgdisk -d 3 -s /dev/sdc
```

Will delete partition 3, then sorts modified partition table.

Comment: I think he needs to wipe out the content of the disk without deleting it.